# "incomplete type" error when accessing a template class

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, incomplete-type

I have a "SignalProcessingBlock" class that contains a "Buffer" template class.
This is how they look like:

```
SignalProcessingBlock.h:

class SignalProcessingBlock{

public:

Buffer <class BufferClass>  *InputBuffer;

Buffer <class BufferClass>  *OutputBuffer;

SignalProcessingBlock   *FrontSignalProcessingBlock;

    void Process();
};

SignalProcessingBlock.cpp:
#include "SignalProcessingBlock.h"
void SignalProcessingBlock::Process()

{
    double tmp;

    for (int i=0;i<(this->InputBuffer->BufferSize/2);i++)

    {

        this->OutputBuffer->buffer[i] = this->InputBuffer->buffer[i*2];

        tmp=this->OutputBuffer->buffer[i];

    }

}

Buffer.h:

template <class BufferClass> class Buffer
{
public:

int         BufferSize;

BufferClass buffer[];

Buffer (BufferClass *buffer,int BufferSize);
};

Buffer.cpp:
#include "Buffer.h"

template <class BufferClass> 

Buffer <BufferClass>::Buffer(BufferClass *buffer,int BufferSize)
{

this->buffer=buffer;

this->BufferSize=BufferSize;
}
```

Even before I try to perform the actions I need I get the following error lines:

```
jni/SignalProcessingBlock.cpp:34:47: error: definition of implicitly-declared 'SignalProcessingBlock::~SignalProcessingBlock()'
In file included from jni/SignalProcessingBlock.h:4:0,
                 from jni/SignalProcessingBlock.cpp:1:
jni/Buffer.h: In instantiation of 'Buffer<BufferClass>':
jni/SignalProcessingBlock.cpp:42:35:   instantiated from here
jni/Buffer.h:9:21: error: 'Buffer<BufferClass>::buffer' has incomplete type
jni/SignalProcessingBlock.h:11:16: error: forward declaration of 'struct BufferClass'
jni/SignalProcessingBlock.cpp: In member function 'void SignalProcessingBlock::Process()':
jni/SignalProcessingBlock.cpp:44:23: error: 'class Buffer<BufferClass>' has no member named 'buffer'
jni/SignalProcessingBlock.cpp:44:54: error: 'class Buffer<BufferClass>' has no member named 'buffer'
jni/SignalProcessingBlock.cpp:45:27: error: 'class Buffer<BufferClass>' has no member named 'buffer'
/cygdrive/d/Development/NDK/android-ndk-r9/build/core/build-binary.mk:348: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/com_talkitt_beta_NativeWrapper/SignalProcessingBlock.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/com_talkitt_beta_NativeWrapper/SignalProcessingBlock.o] Error 1
```

I am writing in C++ and using eclipse Juno, the debugging and building is performed using ndk-build ("make" command wrapper).

I am doing everything by the book and don't understand the error, I do have the "buffer" member and the syntax seems to be correct.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

By the way stack overflow tells me that I need to add some more information for some reason so I am writing just stuff stuff stuff

Comment: Where is `Buffer` defined (are you missing an include)?

Comment: @SleuthEye Please scroll down to see the definition of Buffer

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of the template class `Buffer`, the token `BufferClass` is the parameter of the template. Later when declaring the type of `Buffer` object to be used you need to specialize the template, or in other words specify the actual type to use as the template argument.

In your particular case, if you need an instance of `Buffer` containing an array of `double` values, you might do something like:

```
#include "Buffer.h"
class SignalProcessingBlock{

public:
  Buffer <double>  *InputBuffer;
  ...
```

If on the other hand you wish to defer the template specialization, you would have to make `SignalProcessingBlock` also a template class:

```
#include "Buffer.h"
template <class BufferClass> class SignalProcessingBlock{

public:
  Buffer <typename BufferClass>  *InputBuffer;
  ...
```

Comment: Yes but I have an error even before I create an instance, in the compilation (as I wrote in the original post)..

Comment: @user3378878 you need to specify the complete type for the object you want to instantiate, that is the specialized template with a specific type (as was shown in my code sample where I replaced `class BufferClass` with `double` when declaring the type of `InputBuffer`). Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: @user3378878 I don't want to have a specific type - I want to have a generic buffer those inputs can be int, double, float, bool or whatever, and for now there are no functions that would be implemented differently based on their type.
What you showed me is Template Specialization, and I don't want it for now..

Comment: @user3378878 Operations on buffers of different types are inherently different as far as the mapping to machine code goes (e.g. assignment of a double has to copy 8 bytes, whereas assignment of an int typically copies 4 bytes). You could however defer the template specialization by making `SignalProcessingBlock` also a template class.

Comment: That's a good point but I already tried that.. the thing is I need SignalProcessingBlock to be also virtual later on and C++ doesn't except virtual template classes...

Comment: C++ doesn't accept virtual template classes? I guess you must be talking about something other than [this live demo](http://ideone.com/B0FpT0)... Could you elaborate?